# Fitting Time-series Values with a Gaussian Function

Tags: python, time, ndvi, numpy

I'm trying to fit a stack of NDVI values to a Gaussian model to allow for determining dates of certain NDVI values using Python and NumPy/SciPy. I've attempted to do this with [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

The following is the function I'm using when applying `curve_fit` to the stack

```
def func(x, *p):
    A, mu, sigma = p
    return A * np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))
```

The parameters that I used for the curve fitting are the following

```
p0 = [1., 0., 1.]  # initial guess for the fitting coefficients
newX = np.linspace(date[0], date[-1], (date[-1] - date[0]) + 1)  # range of days of the year between first image in stack and last
```

To get the stack of values for each pixel and apply the curve fit, I used the following nested loop

```
for x in range(imageHeight):
    for y in range(imageWidth):
        lai = imgStack[x, y]
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, date, lai, p0)
        yFit = func(newX, *popt)
```

When I run the script, the output of `yFit` is always just an array of 0.0. The values of the `popt` variable are always the same as `p0` which leads me to believe that the curve was not fit properly. Is the model not suitable for a stack of 20 NDVI values?

Credit to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11507723/1342580) for most of this code.

Comment: Why do you suppose a Gaussian function ought to fit these values? I rather suspect this fitting might be doing something quite a bit different from what you were hoping for, given that you are using a date of 0 as your initial estimate of the peak (`mu`) and assuming a width (`sigma`) of just one day! For some examples and solutions check out http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11546 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70870/.

Comment: @whuber I was suggested the Gaussian function to try and reduce the noise that occurs. I don't have very much experience in statistics so I am basically trying all the possible approaches to see which yield accurate results.

Comment: Not geographic? Move to stats?

Comment: @martin That's a good idea. However, to be on topic on stats this question would have to be substantially reformulated, so I don't recommend migrating it. It usually is not constructive to start by giving a procedure that may be irrelevant to the actual research objective, noting that it is failing, and asking how to fix it up. A good question on stats (or anywhere else, for that matter) will explain what the research goal is, describe the data, and ask for specific help in achieving a clearly-stated objective.

Comment: I am with @whuber on this one. You may "reduce noise" but at the cost of biasing the resulting distribution. I would look into nonlinear smoothing functions more common in temporal analysis such as local polynomial regression (LOWESS). If you are wanting a linear fit you can explore a mixed effects model with an ARIMA-II term.